# Cannot use boost::threads in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, boost-thread

I get the following error using boost::threads in visual studio 2012 (CTP Nov 2012). I'm using boost 1.53.

```
1>boost/config/requires_threads.hpp(29): fatal error C1189: #error :  "Threading support unavaliable: it has been explicitly disabled with BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS"
```

I found advice on the interwebs, to use the multi-threaded c runtime. (I am, doesn't work.) And then there is a vast silence on what to do about this problem. Is boost dropping support for visual studio??

Comment: Are you sure the BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS is not defined? If so, post the code you're compiling. [Visual Studio support](http://www.boost.org/development/tests/release/developer/thread.html) is not dropped to my knowledge.

Comment: Found the problem. I had disabled language extensions (switch /Za) in the foolish hope of writing portable code ;)

Comment: please submit an answer, [so] encourages posting an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) to your own question.

Comment: @Zendel : Enabling `/Za` breaks more than you would think – I would recommend _never_ using it, and ensuring that your code is portable by using multiple compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Threading is automatically disabled in Visual Studio if you disable language extensions (i.e., switch /Za).